# RPi Pico board, using Earl Philhower RP204 library, SPI problem

Tags: spi, raspberrypi-pico

I have tried a number of different programs, trying to get any of several SPI connected displays working with the Pico board.  All of them seem to not initialize the SPI port properly.  For instance, I use the `Adafruit_GFX` library.

The graphicstest demo program I tried unchanged except specifying the ILI9341 chipset, and the following code (obviously the `void setup()` and a few other lines, some commented out are original, to show context, and where in the code my lines have been placed).

The 'code' insert doesn't like the #defines and some of the other lines, sorry for the weird formatting

```cpp
    #define TFT_DC 21
    
    #define TFT_CS 17
    
    #define TFT_RST 20
    
    #define TFT_MOSI 19
    
    #define TFT_SCK 18
    
    
    // Use hardware SPI (on Uno, #13, #12, #11) and the above for CS/DC
    Adafruit_ILI9341 tft = Adafruit_ILI9341(TFT_CS, TFT_DC, TFT_RST);
    // If using the breakout, change pins as desired
    //Adafruit_ILI9341 tft = Adafruit_ILI9341(TFT_CS, TFT_DC, TFT_MOSI, TFT_CLK, TFT_RST, TFT_MISO);
    
    void setup() {
        Serial.begin(115200);
        delay(3000);
        Serial.println("ILI9341 Test!");
    
        bool ret;
        ////ret = setRX(pin_size_t pin);
        ret = SPI.setCS(TFT_CS);
        Serial.printf("setCS =%s\n", ret ? "T" : "F");
        ret = SPI.setSCK(TFT_SCK);
        Serial.printf("setSCK =%s\n", ret ? "T" : "F");
        ret = SPI.setTX(TFT_MOSI);
        Serial.printf("setTX =%s\n", ret ? "T" : "F");
```

What I get is nothing (0V) on the MOSI pin, and the SCK pin (18) shows the following:

[image: Odd 'disturbance' no higher that 1.4V]

Note that this is with no load, not even mounted on a circuit board, using multiple pico boards, all with the same issue.

I also tried using the TFT_eSPI library by Bodmer, which is designed for 32 bit processors including the RP2040, and specifically for displays, with roughly the same result, except that the MOSI pin is held high.

BTW, CS and DS pins, both not part of the SPI hardware seem to be working properly, and I did check, the code is compiling for Hardware SPI.

I'm doing something wrong, and I can't figure out what!

Comment: did you try it without doing the SPI.set... ? do you have `tft.begin();`?

Comment: The ttf.begin is the next line in the program, I didn't put the whole program in since it is an example in the Adafruit_gfx library.  Although I did see an example set of lines I added which just prints out the pin numbers for MOSI, SCK etc, and it turns out I didn't need to do the SPI.set... commands, since those were the default pin assignments.

Comment: For similar displays, I usually leave out the SPI.setCS() since I just use the software controlled CS pin. I'm not sure if it would help, but it's what I would try.

Comment: Arduino by default uses software SPI in the libraries.

Comment: I'd try using the second constructor (commented out line) that [accepts](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_ILI9341/blob/6aad711ce8cc5fb0fc39fc5a5c9b0b71bf410708/Adafruit_ILI9341.cpp#L95) the SPI pins (MISO/MOSI/SCK) and see if that helps. It might be possible the display thinks it is connected to the default SPI pins and so reconfigures the SPI prior to communication, replacing your `setTX`, `setRX` etc

Comment: Dig a bit deeper, looks like my suspicion could be [correct](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-GFX-Library/blob/126007f2c52d3238b7a1133ec14192c3d1deb8a9/Adafruit_SPITFT.cpp#L2065) .. the display does reconfigure the SPI port on demand based on the initial settings

Answer (score 0):

Ok, my bad, I had two problems.  One was I didn't fully check the prototype board I made, there was a whisker short between the clock and the data line, causing the display to not work.  The other is that when I looked at the clock line when not plugged into the board, I didn't believe the signal was correct.

Apparently, the Pico has a bit of noise on the clock line sometimes when it starts to send data, which doesn't appear to affect anything, so I haven't looked at it too closely.

The second thing that really blows my mind, is that the clock signal is consistently no higher than between 1.38 to a maximum of 1.48 volts.  The Data line seems a bit better at just barely over 2V, but the displays I'm using don't seem to mind.  I thought these were 3.3 volt I/O, and expected something at least over 2.5V or so.  And since I had an issue with the wiring to the display, I never saw that it was "OK Anyway".

Thanks for everyone's suggestions.

Comment: The low voltages definitely sound odd. [This post](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?p=1461438&sid=4b988a8f389f81093115a90877e36de4#p1461438) (or thread) *might* help, maybe? Try testing the voltages with nothing attached to the Pico (maybe some peripheral is dragging the voltages down). Or there is another short, that you've not found yet. Or maybe ask a *new question* to see if anyone knows why...

Comment: No, the reason I didn't immediately identify the short was because the pico is 1.46V in free air, connected to nothing but a scope.